# MAAS cluster out of sync

Tags: maas

I have another issue with MAAS. One after the other...

Setting up a second cluster I reached the step of syncing images. Download seems to work fine but cluster stays pathetically Out-of-Sync in the GUI. What could be the problem?

In `/var/lib/maas/boot-resources` I have endless numbers of snapshot-yyyymmdd-hhmmss 
directories...

In maas.log, I have:

```
 /var/lib/maas/boot-resources/snapshot-20150307-155155
Mar  7 16:51:56 node6 maas.boot_image_download_service: [ERROR] Failed to download images: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

In pserv.log, I have:

```
2015-03-07 16:46:56+0100 [-] Logged OOPS id OOPS-adfa7a97ffe207c7b625e278f29be756: URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
2015-03-07 16:51:56+0100 [-] Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 423, in errback
        self._startRunCallbacks(fail)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 490, in _startRunCallbacks
        self._runCallbacks()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1155, in gotResult
        _inlineCallbacks(r, g, deferred)
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1097, in _inlineCallbacks
        result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
        return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/pserv_services/image_download_service.py", line 130, in maybe_start_download
        yield self._start_download()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1097, in _inlineCallbacks
        result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
        return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/pserv_services/image_download_service.py", line 121, in _start_download
        get_proxy_url("https"))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/threadpool.py", line 191, in _worker
        result = context.call(ctx, function, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
        return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
        return func(*args,**kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/utils/twisted.py", line 148, in wrapper
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/rpc/boot_images.py", line 87, in _run_import
        boot_resources.import_images(sources)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/import_images/boot_resources.py", line 268, in import_images
        install_boot_loaders(snapshot_path, image_descriptions.get_image_arches())
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/import_images/boot_resources.py", line 102, in install_boot_loaders
        boot_method.install_bootloader(destination)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/boot/uefi.py", line 191, in install_bootloader
        'main', 'amd64')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/boot/utils.py", line 160, in get_updates_package
        package, archive, component, architecture, release=release)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/boot/utils.py", line 136, in get_package
        package, archive, component, architecture, release=release)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/boot/utils.py", line 115, in get_package_info
        packages = get_packages(archive, component, architecture, release=release)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/boot/utils.py", line 94, in get_packages
        release_file = get_file(release_url)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/boot/utils.py", line 52, in get_file
        response = urllib2.build_opener().open(url)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
        response = self._open(req, data)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
        '_open', req)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
        return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
        raise URLError(err)
    urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>

2015-03-07 16:51:56+0100 [-] Logged OOPS id OOPS-6f24ef492ef8ec698cd54230926ffb2c: URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

Answer (score 1):

After a while found that problem was related to name resolution...

To answer questions on my answer what I did was to fix the problem with upstream DNS server to allow name resolution for internet domains. This solved the problem...

Comment: That describes the cause of your problem, but what exactly did you do to fix it? As it stands, this is more a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just add "dns-nameservers" and "dns-search" to /etc/network/interface, after restart it got synced:


auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static

        address 192.168.110.2

        netmask 255.255.255.0

        network 192.168.110.0

        broadcast 192.168.110.255

        dns-nameservers 10.196.?.? 192.168.110.2 

        dns-search 10.196.?.? 192.168.110.2